# System.InvalidOperationException while dynamically enumerating and retrieving .NET6 Entity Framework DbContext DbSet<...>s instances' records

Tags: reflection, entity-framework-core, runtime-error, .net-6.0, enumeration

The subject runtime error's location is inside the following code. Please advise how to fix this issue.

```
using (var ctx = new MyDbContext())
{
    foreach (var entityInfo in ctx.GetEntitiesInfo())
        System.Console.WriteLine($"{entityInfo.Index}. EntityName = {entityInfo.Name}, Records count = {entityInfo.RecordCount}");
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public readonly record struct EntityInfo (int Index, string? Name, int RecordCount);

    public static IEnumerable<EntityInfo> GetEntitiesInfo(this MyDbContext context)
    {
        var dbSetProperties = context.GetDbSetProperties();
        var dbSets = dbSetProperties.Select(x => x.GetValue(context, null)).ToList();
        var index = 0;
        foreach (IQueryable? dbSet in dbSets)
        {
            ++index;
            // Runtime Error happens on next code line on second iteration
            //   when index = 2:
            //
            // System.InvalidOperationException:
            // 'There is already an open DataReader associated with
            //  this Connection which must be closed first
            //-
            dbSet.Load();
            var items = new List<object>();
            var enumerator = dbSet?.GetEnumerator();
            while (enumerator?.MoveNext() == true)
            {
                var item = enumerator.Current;
                items.Add(item);
            }

            yield return new EntityInfo(index, dbSet?.ElementType?.ToString(), items.Count);
        }
    }
    public static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetDbSetProperties(this MyDbContext context)
    {
        foreach (var property in context.GetType().GetProperties())
            if (property?.PropertyType?.FullName?
                .Contains("Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet`") == true)
                     yield return property;
    }
}
```

**[Update]**

Actually I wanted to develop a generic code to get all `DbSet`(s) of a given `DbContext`. Here it's based on [Ivan Stoev's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5202563/ivan-stoev) answer to this topic:

```
public static IEnumerable<IQueryable<object>> GetDbSets(this MyDbContext context)
{
    var dbSetProperties = context.GetDbSetTypeProperties();
    return dbSetProperties.Select(x => x.GetValue(context, null))
              .Cast<IQueryable<object>>();
}
public static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetDbSetTypeProperties(this MyDbContext context)
{
    foreach (var property in context.GetType().GetProperties())
        if (property?.PropertyType?.FullName?
            .Contains("Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet`") == true)
            yield return property;
}
```

Please advise if the above code can be even more simplified/streamlined.

**[Update 2]**

`GetDbSets()` method can be simplified this way:

```
public static IEnumerable<IQueryable<object>> GetDbSets(this MyDbContext context)
{
    return context
        .GetType()
        .GetRuntimeProperties()
        .Where(x => x.PropertyType?.FullName?.Contains("Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet`") == true)
        .Select(x => x.GetValue(context, null))
        .Cast<IQueryable<object>>();
}
```

but is there any other ways to enumerate all `DbSet`(s) of a given `DbContext`?

Comment: What is `dbSet.Load()` method? Why you do not use `context.Model` for retrieving metadata?

Comment: @Svyatoslav Danyliv: I can't get all `DbSet`(s)'  data records of a given `DbContext` using `context.Model`. Could you please advise how it can be done?

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of flaws in that code snippet, but the concrete problem in question is caused by the lack of disposal of the `IEnumerator` returned by the `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()` call.

I know the non generic `IEnumerator` does not implement `IDisposable`, but that was a miss, and the generic `IEnumerator<T>` added later normally implements both `IEnumerator` and `IDisposable`.

So you have to either account for that and modify the code similar to this:

```cs
var items = new List<object>();
var enumerator = dbSet?.GetEnumerator();
try
{
    while (enumerator?.MoveNext() == true)
    {
        var item = enumerator.Current;
        items.Add(item);
    }
}
finally
{
    (enumerator as IDisposable)?.Dispose();
}
```

or better let the C# `foreach` do that for you (writing behind the scenes a code similar to the above):

```cs
var items = new List<object>();
foreach (var item in dbSet)
    items.Add(item);
```

Note that `DbSet<T>` type properties are the equivalent of `Set<T>()` method and are initialized by EF Core at the `DbContext` instance creation, so neither they nor their content is `null`, hence all the `?.` operators are not needed.

Also calling the `Load` method is not needed since all it does is to enumerate the db set without storing items in a list (basically `foreach` with empty body).

Anyway, both previous code snippets will fix the original issue. But there is even better ways. Since all entities are required to be classes (reference types), each db set can be cast to `IQueryable<object>`

```cs
foreach (IQueryable<object> dbSet in dbSets)
```

which offers some additional benefits.

First, the original code could be fixed just by adding single `using`  statement:

```cs
var items = new List<object>();
using var enumerator = dbSet?.GetEnumerator();
while (enumerator?.MoveNext() == true)
{
    var item = enumerator.Current;
    items.Add(item);
}
```

It can be replaced with `foreach` as before

```cs
var items = new List<object>();
foreach (var item in dbSet)
    items.Add(item);
```

but now you have access to many `Enumerable` (and `Queryable` and EF Core specific) extension methods, so you can replace all the iteration code with simple

```cs
var items = dbSet.ToList();
```

And in case you just need the record count, retrieve it with server side query without loading all the data in memory

```cs
var itemsCount = dbSet.Count();

yield return new EntityInfo(index, dbSet.ElementType.ToString(), itemsCount);
```

Comment: Thank you, it works now based on your corrections. Please see my [Update] section to this topic.